# Jboss 7 and Spring CLOB with Oracle

Tags: oracle, jboss7.x, spring-jdbc

I am using Spring 3.0.7 in JBoss 7.1.1 and am having an issue with Oracle CLOBs.  I have my unit tests passing outside the container.  However i am missing some JBoss API classes from my maven pom.  When i run i get the following error....

> Could not initialize JBossNativeJdbcExtractor because JBoss API classes are not available: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ***org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedConnection***

Anyone have any ideas as to what dependencies i need to include to get this working?

Comment: And you provide a stack trace? Is the exception coming from your code, Spring code or JBoss code?

Comment: the Spring 3.1.1 code is out of date with the changes in JBoss 7.1.1. see below for my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it working!  I cut and pasted the Spring 3.1.1 code and simply replaced the constants with the new packages as in...

```
...
private static final String WRAPPED_CONNECTION_NAME = "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedConnection";
private static final String WRAPPED_STATEMENT_NAME = "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement";
private static final String WRAPPED_RESULT_SET_NAME = "org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedResultSet";
...
```

i then included a jboss-deployment-structure.xml file to include the dependency on the missing class...

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
 <deployment>
      <!-- need this for Spring CLOB along with my custom JBoss7NativeJdbcExtractor -->     
      <dependencies>
           <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters" />
      </dependencies>        
 </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Comment: hi user671731,

can you tell me where you cut and paste the constants code?

Answer (score 0):

You can look at what we did at [oVirt](http://www.ovirt.org) project - although we used postgreSQL as database, I think the have the same issues. However, pay attention we use Spring-jdbc and not "plain" jdbc calls.